# Formula so that $(\forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \forall x \ \psi) \rightarrow \forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$ is not valid

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I am looking for an example of a formula of the form in the title of this post which is not valid.

I am very much looking forward to your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially anything you try will work! For example, the following formula is not valid, when $P$ and $Q$ are unary relation symbols:  $$(\forall x\, P(x) \rightarrow \forall x\, Q(x))\rightarrow \forall x\, (P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$$

For a countermodel, let $M = \{a,b\}$, with $P^M = \{a\}$ and $Q^M = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I really get what you mean. Is $\forall x P(x)$ false because it's not true for the assignment x=b, therefore we can conclude that $\forall x Q(x)$ is true (although it's false), so the left side of the implication is true.(?) But the right side is false since $P(a) $(which equals $\{a\}$) and $P(b)$(which equals $\{a\}$) don't imply $Q(a)$ (which equals $\emptyset$) and $Q(b) $(which equals $\emptyset$) respectively?

Comment: $P(b)$ is false, so $\forall x P(x)$ is false, so $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x Q(x)$ is true. The point is that if $A$ is false, then $A\rightarrow B$ is true, regardless of the truth value of $B$.

Comment: On the other hand, $P(a)\rightarrow Q(a)$ is false, so $\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ is false.

Comment: In total, the big implication is false, since the first part is true and the second part is false.

Comment: Yeah, then I got you right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$(\forall x(x\in\{\varnothing\})\Rightarrow\forall x(x\in\varnothing))\Rightarrow\forall x(x\in\{\varnothing\}\Rightarrow x\in\varnothing)\tag 1$$
$\forall x(x\in\{\varnothing\})$ is false, hence $\forall x(x\in\{\varnothing\})\Rightarrow\forall x(x\in\varnothing)$ is true.
On the other hand, $\forall x(x\in\{\varnothing\}\Rightarrow x\in\varnothing)$ is false, hence $(1)$ is false.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than approaching it in an ad hoc way, just negate the formula:

$$\lnot\bigg((\forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \forall x \ \psi) \rightarrow \forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi)\bigg)$$

$$(\forall x \ \phi \rightarrow \forall x \ \psi) \land \lnot\bigg(\forall x (\phi \rightarrow \psi)\bigg)$$

$$(\lnot \forall x \ \phi \lor \forall x \ \psi) \land \exists x \lnot\bigg(\phi \rightarrow \psi\bigg)$$

$$(\exists x \ \lnot \phi \lor \forall x \ \psi) \land \exists x (\phi \land \lnot \psi)$$

$\exists x \ \lnot \psi$ contradicts $\forall x \ \psi$, so the left hand side can be simplified

$$(\exists x \ \lnot \phi) \land \exists x (\phi \land \lnot \psi)$$

So you just need an example where $\phi$ is sometimes false, sometimes true, and somewhere it is true that $\psi$ is false.

So $\phi ~:~ \text{x is even}$ is sometimes true and sometimes false.  Pick a point where it is true, $x=4$, and make $\psi$ false there, $\psi(x) \equiv (x \ne 4)$.

Comment: Clever approach, thank you!